# Ember & Typescript - defining actions

Tags: typescript, ember.js

I am trying to create my first ember app with typescript and I have trouble with how actions are defined. According to several tutorials I found, I should use decorator @action like this:

```
import { action } from '@ember-decorators/object';

@action sayHello(){
}
```

But I am getting error:

> Module '"../../../node_modules/@ember-decorators/object"' has no
>   exported member 'action'.

In my package.json I have defined:

```
"ember-decorators": "^6.0.0",
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `import { action } from '@ember/object';` ?

Comment: have you tried using https://github.com/typed-ember/ember-cli-typescript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@action` decorator was removed in `ember-decorators` v6 because it was added to Ember in v3.10 beta.

Therefore you should either downgrade `ember-deocrators` to v5.1 so you can use it with current version of Ember or upgrade Ember to at least 3.10-beta.

If you choose to upgrade Ember, the new way to import the action decorator is `import { action } from '@ember/object';`